# Android - Replace parameterized enum with @IntDef

Tags: java, android, enums

How can i avoid parameterized enum **with @IntDef**.

1. I want keep some static details associated with each enum/type (like associated URl , associated drawable etc.).

   ```
   TYPE_ONE(R.string.res, Urls.URL1),

   TYPE_TWO(R.string.res, Urls.URL2),

   TYPE_THREE(R.string.res, Urls.URL3),

   TYPE_FOUR(R.string.res, Urls.URL4),

   TYPE_FIVE(R.string.res, Urls.URL5),

   TYPE_SIX(R.string.res, Urls.URL6);

   private final int mResId;
   private final String mUrl;

   Types(int titleResId, String url) {
     mResId = titleResId;
     mUrl = url;
   }

   public int getRes() {
      return mTitleResId;
   }

   public String getURL() {
      return mUrl;
   }
   ```

Whats the optimized way to do this?

Comment: what you're describing seems like a legit reason for using enums

Comment: So that i can avoid switch/if statements.EnumClassName.TYPE_ONE.getURL() will return corresponding URL.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Say , I have 10 different activities each will load a URL,with a Title.May be i can hard-code the URL & Title in each Activity.But if i go for enum , i can centralize every details & i just need to pass enum from the Main Activity.

Comment: so it still sounds like a good scenario for using an enum, why do you want to use IntDef?

Comment: But Google strongly recommonds to avoid enums.:(.Please have a read https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/magic-constants-in-android-development

Comment: @DonChakkappan Do you read end of this post? Also read https://plus.google.com/+JakeWharton/posts/bTtjuFia5wm (link to this located in the end of post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that `enum`s consume much more resources than integers and there is a ban on them on Android, however, in situations like the one you're describing I think the overhead is compensated by the gain in readability.

That being said, one way to use `@IntDef` and link more variables to it could be to have privately and statically declare arrays of whatever resource you need, and access them with static getters passing the `@IntDef`.

```
public class Constants {

    public static final int PAGE_ONE = 0;
    public static final int PAGE_TWO = 1;
    public static final int PAGE_THREE = 2;

    @IntDef(value={PAGE_ONE, PAGE_TWO, PAGE_THREE})
    public @interface PageType {}

    private static final SparseArray<String> PAGE_TITLES = new SparseArray<>();
    private static final SparseArray<Integer> PAGE_IMAGES = new SparseArray<>();
    static {
        PAGE_TITLES.put(PAGE_ONE, "PAGE_ONE");
        PAGE_IMAGES.put(PAGE_ONE, R.drawable.page_one);

        PAGE_TITLES.put(PAGE_TWO, "PAGE_TWO");
        PAGE_IMAGES.put(PAGE_TWO, R.drawable.page_two);

        PAGE_TITLES.put(PAGE_THREE, "PAGE_THREE");
        PAGE_IMAGES.put(PAGE_THREE, R.drawable.page_three);
    }

    public static int getPageDrawable(@PageType int pageNumber){
        return PAGE_IMAGES.get(pageNumber);
    }

    public static String getPageTitle(@PageType int pageNumber){
        return PAGE_TITLES.get(pageNumber);
    }

    private Constants(){}
}
```